# activerecord attribute based on a join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building a sort of reddit clone to pick up rails again. I have a table `posts` and a table `votes`.

Posts:

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.string :title
end
```

Votes:

```
create_table :votes do |t|
  t.belongs_to :post
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.string :sort_of_vote
end
```

I want to retrieve a list of posts with a boolean attribute per post if it is liked by a user or not.

So I would like to something like:

`Post.all.first.liked?`

I'm thinking of a good way to do this. What I don't want: a query per liked? method call. What would be a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Read about **[Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)**, specifically the section on **Solution to N + 1 queries problem** which uses **[`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes)**

```
@posts = Post.includes(:votes)
```

Now you can create a method on `Post` like

```
def liked?
  !votes.empty?
end
```

and call it without forcing a query for each item in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
class User
  def liked_posts
    @liked_posts ||= self.votes.posts
  end
  def likes?(post)
    @liked_posts.include?(post)
  end
end

class Post
  def liked?(user)
    user.liked_posts.include?(self)
  end
end
```

This should retrieve the list of liked posts once and cache it.  Then when you call post.liked?(user) or user.likes?(post) it will be able to use the cached data to determine if the user likes that post.

Comment: I *think* he's looking for a collection of posts with a flag on each instance for whether it's been liked by 1+ users or not.

Comment: @Deefour if that's the case, then your answer is much better than mine.  I assumed he was looking to put a checkmark next to a post if the user had liked it.

Comment: Sorry about not being totally clear :( I was looking for marking the upvote arrow as "checked" when the user has liked it. So I think this answer is more what I was looking for. I was thinking of something like this myself but I was wondering if there maybe was a more rails-y way to do it.

Comment: And how does something like `self.votes.posts` work? That doesn't work in my rails console.

Comment: Look at http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_self.html for an explanation of `self` in ruby.  In this case `self` is an instance of the class.  So you would need to do

    `user = User.where(<find a user>); user.votes.posts`